# what padding strategy is used by SunJCE SHA1WithRSA

Tags: java, rsa, padding, digital-signature, jce

Normally both `PSS` and `PKCS1v15` can be used for RSA signatures padding.
And for java the code is also simple, but it just can't tell the padding strategy used.
My code:

```
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA");
signature.initSign(privateKey);
signature.update(plainBytes);
byte[] signBytes = signature.sign();
```

May I explicitly define `PSS` with `MGF1` as the padding strategy using SunJCE as provider?

Comment: I have tested that it is using `PKCS1v15` as padding strategy, but still have no idea whether `SunJCE` supports `PSS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PSS` is not present in the supported algorithms list of [SunJCE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html). However `SHA256withRSA/PSS` is implemented in [android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.html).

I suggest to use BouncyCastle

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA/PSS");
sig.initSign(privateKey);
sig.update(data);
byte[] signature = sig.sign();
```

**UPDATED**

The default `maskGenAlgorithm` in  [PKCS#1 v2.1](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt) is MGF1.

> ```
> RSASSA-PSS-params ::= SEQUENCE {
>    hashAlgorithm      [0] OAEP-PSSDigestAlgorithms  DEFAULT sha1,
>    maskGenAlgorithm   [1] PKCS1MGFAlgorithms  DEFAULT mgf1SHA1,
>    saltLength         [2] INTEGER  DEFAULT 20,
>    trailerField       [3] INTEGER  DEFAULT 1
>  }
> ```

I assume BouncyCastle is using it. You can define your own PSS parameters. For example (see [PSSParameterSpec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/PSSParameterSpec.html#DEFAULT))

```
sig.setParameter(PSSParameterSpec.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: I have not seen any sign of `MGF1`, is it default?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the answer, just to add a snippet that shows how to set all the params manually, and of course `BouncyCastle` has to be used:

```
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA/PSS", "BC"); //second param "BC" is not really required
MGF1ParameterSpec mgf1ParameterSpec = new MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-256"); 
PSSParameterSpec pssParameterSpec = new PSSParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", mgf1ParameterSpec , 20, 1);
signature.setParameter(pssParameterSpec);
signature.initSign(privateKey);
signature.update(plainBytes);
byte[] signBytes = signature.sign();
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks @xuanzhui

Here is how I successfully verified my (hex encoded) signature:

```
public static boolean verify(String plainText, String signature, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
    Signature publicSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA512withRSA/PSS");
    publicSignature.setParameter(new PSSParameterSpec("SHA-512", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA512 , 64, 1));
    publicSignature.initVerify(publicKey);
    publicSignature.update(plainText.getBytes(UTF_8));

    return publicSignature.verify(hexToBytes(signature));
}
```

Note despite the documentation suggesting otherwise (`getSaltLength()` - "returns the salt length in bits") salt length seems to be in **bytes**!

Also I think "SHA512withRSA/PSS" is only supported from Android 23+